# Custom segue to a navigation controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue

I am using a custom segue to slide my views over. The custom subclass works fine whenever it moves from a view controller to a view controller, but it crashes when I try to move from a view controller to a navigation controller. (It carries over the previous navigation bar and when I try to click the screen it crashes.)

This is the custom segue

```
class FromRightSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
override func perform() {
    let src = self.source
    let dst = self.destination
    src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: .curveEaseInOut,
                   animations: {
                    dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    },
                   completion: { finished in
                   src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    )
}
}
```

When I use the built in segues like show the segue works fine, but there is no built in segue that moves from the right. Any suggestions?